The definition of inconsistency in a logical theory
A classical definition of inconsistency is

the theory leads to contradictory statements

Shoenfield: Mathematical Logic defines this on page 42 that

A theory T is inconsistent if every formula of T is a theorem of T

I guess this is because in classical logic there's the ex falso quodlibet rule, from false implies everything, which is a corollary of having contradictory statements.
Is my argument correct, and this is why Shoenfield defines inconsistency this way?

There are two "natural" definition of consistency. The first one is:

A theory [set of formulas] $\Gamma$ is inconsistent if $Γ \vdash \varphi$ for every $\varphi$,

the other being:

$\Gamma$ is consistent if there is no formula $\varphi$ such that both : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

We can prove that the two are equivalent, using usual logic rules.
The equivalence of the two is expressed by Shoenfield at page 42. Given the definition of inconsistency: every formula of $T$ is a theorem of $T$, we have that: "if for some formula $A$, both $A$ and $\lnot A$ are theorems of $T$, then $T$ is inconsistent [apply tautological consequence]."
The explanation relies on the deinition of tautological consequence (page 26) and applying it to $A, \lnot A$ and a formula $B$ whatever, from which it follows that $A \to (\lnot A \to B)$ is a tautology.
Then applying the Corollary of the Tautology Theorem (page 27), we have that $A \to (\lnot A \to B)$ is a theorem. And this is EFQ.
